# CSS3 transition does not work

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have this css code and which i added to my style to have a transition but it does not work so could anyone tell me what is wrong so I can fix it

this is my css code

```
div p
{
-webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: width 2s;

}
div:hover p
{
     width: 300px;
}
```

this is my html code

```
<div><p style='background-color:blue'>Hello</p></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add

```
width: 100%;
```

to your `div p { }` and it will work. You need to give CSS start and end values.

So, your final CSS will be:

```
div p {
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
    width: 100%;
}

div:hover p {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Yep, we are on the same page +1

Answer (score 1):

You need a starting width, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7gqo4o1h/4/

```
div p
{
width: 100%;  
-webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: width 2s;

}
div:hover p
{
     width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Duplication of the answer above.